# How to map a list to a column with repeating values python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a list of .png logos like so:

```
logos

['C.png',
 'E.png',
 'FUR.png',
 'FaZe.png',
 'GenG.png',
 'HER.png',
 'MiBR.png',
 'X6.png']
```

I have another column consisting of those values repeating multiple times, like so:

```
teams

HER
MiBR
C
E
HER
FaZe
...
```

You get the idea. Now what I would like to do is map the logos values (the .pngs) to their corresponding team, like so:

```
teams   logos
HER     HER.png
MiBR    MiBR.png
C       C.png
E       E.png
HER     HER.png
FaZe    FaZe.png
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does all of this items follow the same format "{name}.png"?

Comment: yep all of the items follow the same format. Only difference between the two is the ".png" like you menion.

Comment: Then why not just add a png to these column, like this:

df.column_name + ".png"

Comment: What if some elements present in the series are missing in the list? if not then just add the `.png` string to the series

Answer (score 2):

Creating DataFrame and lists:

```
pngs = ['C.png', 'E.png','FUR.png', 'FaZe.png', 'GenG.png', 'HER.png', 'MiBR.png', 'X6.png']

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'teams': ['HER','MiBR','C','E','HER','FaZe','teste']})
```

Getting only names of .png list:

```
pngs_only_name = [x[:-4] for x in pngs]

['C', 'E', 'FUR', 'FaZe', 'GenG', 'HER', 'MiBR', 'X6']
```

The elements present in the series that are missing in the list we'll have a None value:

```
dataframe['logos'] = dataframe.teams.apply(lambda x: (x+'.png') if x in pngs_only_name else None)
```

Results:

```
    teams   logos
0   HER     HER.png
1   MiBR    MiBR.png
2   C       C.png
3   E       E.png
4   HER     HER.png
5   FaZe    FaZe.png
6   teste   None
```